# Simplifying in propositional logic with only negations, disjunctions, and conjunctions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Sometimes when solving some exercises of propositional logic I have some doubts of whether a certain expression could be more simplified. But it is worse when I get an exercise and I cannot see exactly how to simplify it after using some of the laws.

The exercise is:

$$ (\neg p \lor\neg q) \land( p \lor q)$$

I tried using distributive law and Morgan law, and even introduced some conditionals to try to transform it, but still I cannot simplify the expression.

Comment: Doing the truth table it appears to be $ \neg (p \leftrightarrow q)$ @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I firstly did the truth table ( I didn't do it first because I wanted to work with the different laws and learn to see how to apply them). This is left as it follows:

\begin{array}{ccccc} 
p & q & (\neg p \lor \neg q) & (p \lor q) & (\neg p \lor \neg q) \land (p \lor q)\\
\hline \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}

After this, and seeing that this was equal to $ \neg(p \leftrightarrow q) $ I tried to find it using the different laws. The procedure I followed was:

$$(\neg p \lor \neg q) \land (p \lor q) 
= [ (\neg p \lor \neg q) \land p] \lor[(\neg p \lor \neg q) \land q] \\
= [(\neg q \land p) \lor (\neg p \land q)] \\
= [\neg(q \lor \neg p) \lor \neg (p \lor \neg q)] \\
= [\neg (p \rightarrow q) \lor \neg(q \rightarrow p)]  \\
= \neg [(p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow p)] \\
= \neg (p \leftrightarrow q)$$

Comment: Also you can use an equivalence $(p \rightarrow q) \leftrightarrow (\neg p \lor q)$ to transform both disjunctions and end up with $p \leftrightarrow \neg q$ which is equivalent to $\neg (p \leftrightarrow q)$.